# Post with ajax-jquery send blank space when the sentence have +

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am sending a request by post using jquery ajax, but some of the words i send have + to join words like: HTA+HIPERAQUITISM+DBLR, the php recieve HTA HIPERAQUITISM DBLR changing the + by blank spaces, i post the code below. help!

```
          function getItemInfo(itemName, itemField, itemComparative, itemTable){

                       var result = "";
                       var nombreItem = itemName;
                       var campoItem = itemField;
                       var comparativeItem = itemComparative;
                       var tableItem = itemTable;


                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            url: 'modules/medicos/controller.php?fun=consul_item&nombre_item=consul_item'+
                                  '&nombre_item='+nombreItem+
                                 '&campo='+campoItem+
                                 '&comparador='+comparativeItem+
                                 '&tabla='+tableItem,
                            success: function(data) {
                                result = data.toString();
                            },
                            failure: function() {
                                result = "";
                            }
                        });
                       return result;
                   }//end function
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused what it is you want to do... Do you have some strings that you want to send that include the '+' character, and you want that to be preserved as that character rather than being treated as a white-space replacement and converted back to white-space?

Answer (score 1):

This is because in a URL + means space.

You'll need to URL encode the data first before adding it to the query string.

You can use the [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) function to encode your value before adding it to the query string.

Once your PHP code picks it up you can then decode the value with the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function

So your code should update to something like this:

```
url: 'modules/medicos/controller.php?fun=consul_item&nombre_item=consul_item'+
                                  '&nombre_item='+encodeURIComponent(nombreItem)+
                                 '&campo='+encodeURIComponent(campoItem)+
                                 '&comparador='+encodeURIComponent(comparativeItem)+
                                 '&tabla='+encodeURIComponent(tableItem),
```

Comment: It's actually encodeURIComponent() to encode the + character (along with a few others), escape() and encodeURI() leave it intact.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. You are passing those variables one by one (nombreItem, campoItem, comparativeItem and tableItem). So I don't really understand what you say is not working.

A suggestion to make passing data easier:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      url: 'modules/medicos/controller.php',
      data : ({ fun : consul_item,
                  nombre_item : nombreItem,
                  campo : campoItem,
                  comparador : comparativeItem,
                  tabla : tableItem }), 
      success: function(data) {
            result = data;
      },
      failure: function() {
            result = "";
      }
});
```

If you want to pass all your info as one textual string you should do:

```
...
data: ({ test : consul_item + '+' + nombreItem + '+' + campoItem + '+' + comparativeItem + '+' + tableItem }), 
...
```